# Performing operations on certain rows of certain columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to solve the following problem for the past while.

I have a dataframe with 7 columns and a variable number of rows, between 10 and 20, that I read in from an csv file. I would like to perform the following operation: divide columns A, B, C, D of the row corresponding to unique_string1 by 4 and add these values to unique_string2's A, B, C, D columns.

```
     Title               Description   A    B   C   D
0    unique_string1                    2    1   4   6
1    unique_string2                    6    2   4   5
2    unique_string3         B          1    8   8   2
3    unique_string4         B          1    1   2   3
4    unique_string5         C          3    1   2   5
```

Comment: Could you provide the expected answer for you example as the question is not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

To get values for specific columns in a specific DataFrame row:

```
vals = df.loc[df['Title']=='unique_string1', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].values
```

Divide these by 4:

```
vals /= 4
```

Add back to 'unique_string2' row in DF:

```
df.loc[df['Title']=='unique_string2', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] += vals
```

I would recommend reading the documentation for the DataFrame.loc operator in pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html